# Python/Excel - IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlsxwriter

Attempting to extract .xlsx docs from a file and compile the data into a single worksheet.

Receiving a IOError despite that the files exist

Program is as follows

```
#-------------- loop that pulls in files from folder--------------
import os

#create directory from which to pull the files
rootdir = r'C:\Users\username\Desktop\Mults'

for subdir, dir, files in os.walk(rootdir):
for file in files:
    print os.path.join(subdir,file)
#----------------------merge work books-----------------------

import xlrd
import xlsxwriter


wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('merged.xls')
ws = wb.add_worksheet()
for file in files:
    r = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
    head, tail = os.path.split(file)
    count = 0
    for sheet in r:
        if sheet.number_of_rows()>0:
            count += 1
    for sheet in r:
        if sheet.number_of_rosw()>0:
            if count == 1:
                sheet_name = tail
            else:
                sheet_name = "%s_%s" (tail, sheet.name)
            new_sheet = wb.create_sheet(sheet_name)
            new_sheet.write_reader(sheet)
            new_sheet.close()
wb.close()
```

Return error as follows

```
doc1.xlsx
doc2.xlsx
doc3.xlsx
doc4.xlsx

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Work\Python\excel practice\xlsx - loops files - 09204.py", line 23, in <module>
    r = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 394, in open_workbook
    f = open(filename, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'doc1.xlsx'
```

Any suggestions or changes?

Also, any advice if I'm heading in the right direction?

I'm new to the python world, so any advice will be much appreciated!

Thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

You are opening the plain filename without the path; you are ignoring the directory component.

Don't just print the `os.path.join()` result, actually use it:

```
filename = os.path.join(subdir, file) 
r = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
```

Comment: are you suggesting that I replace the print syntax with the syntax you gave?

Comment: @MikeV.: I am suggesting you replace the `xlrd.open_workbook()` call with the code I gave.

Comment: Alright thanks! So I've replaced it and am now receiving this error for sheet in r:
TypeError: 'Book' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem...

Instead of:

```
r = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
```

Use:

```
r = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(subdir,file))
```

For the TypeError:
Instead of:

```
for sheet in r:
    if sheet.number_of_rows()>0:
        count += 1
```

Use:

```
for nsheet in r.sheet_names() #you need a list of sheet names to loop throug
    sheet = r.sheet_by_name(nsheet) #then you create a sheet object with each name in the list
    if sheet.nrows>0: #use the property nrows of the sheet object to count the number of rows
        count += 1
```

Do the same for the second for loop.